# Using jQuery with collapse menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently my side menu consists of parent and child pages. To keep the menu expanded on the child page I am having to use a `switch` statement and check if the url is what I am looking for and if it matches show the expanded child items.

```
 $(function () {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        switch (url) {
            case 'Path1':
                $('#ChildOne').show();
                break;
            case 'Path2':
                $('#ChildTwo').show();
                break;
            case 'Path3':
                $('#ChildThree').show();
                break;
            ...
        }
    });
```

I've got over 20 pages where I need to display the child elements. My question is, is this the only way or does someone know a better way? Thanks in advance for your help.

**Note**

I only want to display the relevant child elements on active child page. Suppose, I click on `ChildOne` when I get redirected to that page I only want to see the child elements under that parent.

My mark-up is as follows

```
<ul>
    <li class="parent"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Parent One</a>
        <ul class="child" id="ChildOne">
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent One</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Parent Two</a>
        <ul class="child" id="ChildTwo">
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Parent Three</a>
        <ul class="child" id="ChildThree">
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added some code in order to be able to reproduce the issue. I added some classes to the parent items of the menu so that I can check them later in order to hide or not their children. The class names are the page name (final word on the url) which is unique. I get it using the substring method.

In this example, your current page is the second option, and by using the `each()` function of jquery, you can go through the elements without having a ton of switch cases or if statements.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rn30dsuk/11/)

Code snippet:

```js
function escocha() {
    var url = '/about/profile'
    var n = url.lastIndexOf("/");
    var myClassName = url.substring(n + 1, url.length)

    alert("The url: " + url);
    alert("The class name: " + myClassName);

    $(".child").each(function (index) {
        alert(this.id);
        if (this.className.indexOf(myClassName) > -1) { // if any class name for this element contains the string 'display'
            alert("I am the current page so my menu items won't collapse!");
        } else {
            $('#' + this.id).hide();
        }
    });
}

$("#esmaga").click(function () {
    escocha();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="parent"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Parent One</a>

        <ul class="child display" id="ChildOne">
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent One</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent One</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Parent Two</a>

        <ul class="child profile" id="ChildTwo">
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Two</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Two</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Two</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Parent Three</a>

        <ul class="child display" id="ChildThree">
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Three</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Of Parent Three</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>...</ul>
<button id="esmaga">Esmaga</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I've just tried your code but I still have the same issue when the child page loads the dropdown is collapsed and not expanded

Comment: What have you done exactly? You can write class names that match the url (or part of it, then see if it is contained in the url) and skip the `hide()` function

Comment: The `hide()` function I've removed for now. The ` escocha()` function, I've placed inside my `$('.parent > a').click(function (){});`. And the if block includes the classes name.

Comment: Well, what's the result? Do all the items collapse?

Comment: Yes all the items are collapsed when I'm redirected to the child page

Comment: Have you added the classes to the ul's?

Comment: Yes I've added the classes to the `ul`, Initially, I hide all the `child` elements and once it's redirected to the `child` page I want to only show the that particular group of `li` expanded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82617/discussion-between-chiapa-and-code).

Answer (score 1):

you can use id of ULs elements same as window.location.pathname. In this case you can call:

```
try{
   $("#"+window.location.pathname).show();
}catch(e){
   // error handling
}
```

but your menu is strange ;)

OK, one more version with object

```
var oPath = new Object({
        "Path1":"ChildOne",
        "Path2":"ChildTwo",
        "Path3":"ChildThree"
});

try{
     $("#"+ oPath[window.location.pathname]).show();
}catch(e){}
```

Comment: Sorry, but how's this different to what I already have? I'm trying to avoid repeating the code.

Comment: Add now more example for your case. It's avoid repeats